# How to build a multimap from a list of tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala, multimap

Suppose I have a list of tuples `List[(A, B)]`. What is the best way to convert it to a `multimap`, which maps `A` to `Set[B]`? Can I build an *immutable* `multimap` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Can I build an immutable multimap ?

Not with the `MultiMap` in Scala standard library. Of course, you can write your own.

> What is the best way to convert it to a multimap?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap, Set, MultiMap}

def list2multimap[A, B](list: List[(A, B)]) = 
  list.foldLeft(new HashMap[A, Set[B]] with MultiMap[A, B]){(acc, pair) => acc.addBinding(pair._1, pair._2)}
```

Answer (score 19):

I'm a bit confused, `Multimap` doesn't map `A` to `Set[B]`, it maps `A` to `B` where `B` can have many values.  Since you want something immutable, I'm going to change this to `Map[A, Set[B]]` which isn't a `Multimap` but does one of the things you said you wanted.

```
// This is your list of (A, B)
val l = List((1, "hi"),
             (2, "there"),
             (1, "what's"),
             (3, "up?"))
// Group it and snip out the duplicate 'A'
// i.e. it initially is Map[A, List[(A, B)]] and we're going to convert it
// to Map[A, Set[B]]
val m = l.groupBy(e => e._1).mapValues(e => e.map(x => x._2).toSet)
println(m)
// Prints: Map(3 -> Set(up?), 1 -> Set(hi, what's), 2 -> Set(there))
```

Comment: You can also use `mapValues`, which won't actually produce a new collection, but will act as a mapped `view` on values.

Comment: `mapValues` - nice.  I've never used that one before.  Updated to use that instead.

Comment: cleaner still: `val m = l groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map {_._2} toSet)`

Comment: That's not cleaner, it's just less characters.

Comment: mapValues means an overhead every time a lookup is performed. A workaround is to do .map(identity). Credit tpolecat and referer on #scala

Comment: Use map directly: `list.groupBy(_._1).map{case(x, xs) => (x, xs.map(_._2))}`