# Scala: Grouping list of tuples

Tags: scala

I need to group list of tuples in some unique way.

For example, if I have

```
val l = List((1,2,3),(4,2,5),(2,3,3),(10,3,2))
```

Then I should group the list with second value and map with the set of first value

So the result should be

```
Map(2 -> Set(1,4), 3 -> Set(2,10))
```

By so far, I came up with this

```
l groupBy { p => p._2 } mapValues { v => (v map { vv => vv._1 }).toSet }
```

This works, but I believe there should be a much more efficient way...

Comment: I think your solution is fine

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209807/how-to-build-a-multimap-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-scala). Basically, as @serejja said, your approach is correct and also the most concise one. You could use `collection.breakOut` as builder factory argument to the last `map` and thereby save the additional iteration to get the `Set` type:

```
l.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1)(collection.breakOut): Set[Int])
```

You shouldn't probably go beyond this, unless you really need to squeeze the performance.

---

Otherwise, this is how a general `toMultiMap` function could look like which allows you to control the values collection type:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.mutable

def toMultiMap[A, K, V, Values](xs: TraversableOnce[A])
    (key: A => K)(value: A => V)
    (implicit cbfv: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, V, Values]): Map[K, Values] = {
  val b = mutable.Map.empty[K, mutable.Builder[V, Values]]
  xs.foreach { elem =>
    b.getOrElseUpdate(key(elem), cbfv()) += value(elem)
  }
  b.map { case (k, vb) => (k, vb.result()) } (collection.breakOut)
}
```

What it does is, it uses a mutable Map during building stage, and values gathered in a mutable `Builder` first (the builder is provided by the `CanBuildFrom` instance). After the iteration over all input elements has completed, that mutable map of builder values is converted into an immutable map of the values collection type (again using the `collection.breakOut` trick to get the desired output collection straight away).

Ex:

```
val l                    = List((1,2,3),(4,2,5),(2,3,3),(10,3,2))
val v                    = toMultiMap(l)(_._2)(_._1)  // uses Vector for values
val s: Map[Int, Set[Int] = toMultiMap(l)(_._2)(_._1)  // uses Set for values
```

So your annotated result type directs the type inference of the values type. If you do not annotate the result, Scala will pick `Vector` as default collection type.